# Powershell script regex single and double quotes

Tags: powershell

I want to replace comma with Chinese comma

the code is

```
$t = $t -replace '(\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}) ,', '$1`u{ff0c}'
```

`u{X} works inside double quote

```
Write-Host "`u{ff0c}"
```

prints ，

but

if I use double quote then regex $1 will not work.

What shall I do ?

Comment: Use double quotes and escape it with a back tick `

Comment: There are several solutions for the question but you need supply a valid input example  (what is in `$t`?) / [mcve] to correctly answer this. Why not just: `$t -replace ',', 'u{ff0c}'`? Hint, see: [quoting rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules). You might also [`[Regex]::Unescape`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape) the `replace with` part: `$t -replace '(\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}) ,', [Regex]::Unescape('$1\uff0c')` which I think should actually standard behavior of `-Replace`.

Comment: See: [`#17826` `-Replace` should (be able to) `[Regex]::Unescape` the `<substitute>`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17826)